# Is it possible to link two wireless internet routers together wirelessly to share a single internet connection?

Tags: wireless-bridge, router

I have my house connected to the internet by high speed 5GHz wireless point to point link.
Within the house is both a wired and wireless network.  The wireless network is served by a linksys internet WRT54GC.

I now have an office that is not connected to the main house but will have it's own network.
The wireless network in the house has a reasonable signal in the office.  I have another WRT54GC and I'm wondering if it's possible to connect them together such that I can plug the IP desk phone into it and my desktop computer (which doesn't have a wireless network card) and yet be able to see the internet and house computer?

This is what it will look like:

```
Ubiquity Bullet ---- (WAN) WRT54GC (LAN) ----- House Computer
                             | 
                             +---------------- WRT54GC (Office LAN)
                               (Wireless)
```

i.e. something like this:

[image]

Is this supported by the WRT54GC firmware?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, you want to use "repeater" mode.

if your router does not support Repeater mode then take a look at DDWRT - which is free open source firmware.

you only need this on the one router.

so your first WRT54GC with WAN would be regular wireless/router.

your second WRT54GC would be a Repeater (don't even need a cable)

hope this helps.

EDIT: link.  http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Universal_Wireless_Repeater

Luc

Comment: Ok thanks.  Looks like my WRT54GC doesn't support ddwrt.  However, I have another router that looks like it might be.  I'll try to flash that and see weather it'll work.

Comment: no problem, good luck.

if you follow the link I posted above it should work fine, that is what I do here at home and it works great.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  The WRT54GC wasn't supported.  So in the end I bought a WRT54GL which is.  Updated stock firmware to DDWRT and now I have a wireless client bridge and VPN set up.  It's fantastic!